# Using lapply and tryCatch returns only one record, not multiple

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am still new to R and I am trying to use lapply and tryCatch to access data via the pro-football-reference site but the code I use below only returns 1 table.

I would like to get all records that exist. Some URL's won't exist which is why I am using tryCatch to skip over these. Here is my attempt:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#create a master dataframe to store all of the results
complete <- data.frame()

datesVector <- c("201909080", "201909050")
teamsVector <- c("chi", "crd", "car")

  for (i in 1:length(datesVector)) {
  for (j in 1:length(teamsVector)) {
    
    # create a url template 
    URL.base <- "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/"
    URL.end <- ".htm"
    
    #create the dataframe with the dynamic values
    URL <- paste0(URL.base, datesVector[i], teamsVector[j], URL.end)
    
    tryCatch({
      
       dfList <- lapply(URL, function(i) {
        webpage <- read_html(i)
        draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
        draft <- html_table(draft_table)[[3]]
                   
      })
    }, error = function(e) print(URL)
    )               
    
    complete <- do.call(rbind, dfList) 
            
  }
}
```

I am going to have a really long vector with many dates and multiple teams and want to try every combination and if the page exists, pull out the data in the table and add it to my dataframe.

But the code below only returns 22 observations, from this link:

```
https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909050chi.htm
```

When in fact, there is another page that exists (and should therefore return data), being another 22 observatons:

```
https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909080car.htm
```

The other team has been included above to try to test the error and skip over it.

What am I doing wrong with the above?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you are using `lapply` because the way you have things set up your `URL` vector will always have length 1 so there's just one thing go look at. The other problem seems to be in your for loop you are constantly replacing the value of `complete` with only the results from that iteration rather than appending to what came before.

Comment: ok, as I'm still learning, are you able to provide a hint on how this should be set up? Why does the `URL` vector always have length 1?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to your task which uses `purrr` and a few other `tidyverse` methods.  See explanation below.

```
library(tidyverse)

combos <- expand.grid(team = teamsVector, date = datesVector)
urls <- paste0(URL.base, combos$date, combos$team, URL.end)

output <- urls %>% 
  map(possibly(read_html, otherwise = NA_character_)) %>%
  discard(is.character) %>%
  map(function(html) html_nodes(html, 'table') %>% html_table) %>%
  pluck(3) %>%
  map_dfr(function(data) {
    col_lvl1 <- colnames(data)
    col_lvl2 <- data[1, ] %>% unname
    actual_data <- data[2:nrow(data), ] %>% unname
    col_multi_lvl <- paste(col_lvl1, col_lvl2, sep = "_")
    colnames(actual_data) <- col_multi_lvl
    return(actual_data %>% as_tibble(.name_repair = make.names))
  }) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Passing_Cmp, "Passing|Cmp", negate = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-starts_with("X_")), as.numeric)
```

Output:

```
output %>% head(15)
# A tibble: 15 x 22
   X_Player X_Tm  Passing_Cmp Passing_Att Passing_Yds...5 Passing_TD Passing_Int Passing_Sk Passing_Yds...9
   <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Matthew… DET            27          45             385          3           0          3              24
 2 Kerryon… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
 3 C.J. An… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
 4 Ty John… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
 5 Marvin … DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
 6 T.J. Ho… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
 7 Danny A… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
 8 Kenny G… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
 9 J.D. Mc… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
10 Jesse J… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
11 Nick Ba… DET             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
12 Kyler M… ARI            29          54             308          2           1          5              33
13 David J… ARI             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
14 Christi… ARI             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
15 Chase E… ARI             0           0               0          0           0          0               0
# … with 13 more variables: Passing_Lng <dbl>, Passing_Rate <dbl>, Rushing_Att <dbl>, Rushing_Yds <dbl>,
#   Rushing_TD <dbl>, Rushing_Lng <dbl>, Receiving_Tgt <dbl>, Receiving_Rec <dbl>, Receiving_Yds <dbl>,
#   Receiving_TD <dbl>, Receiving_Lng <dbl>, Fumbles_Fmb <dbl>, Fumbles_FL <dbl>
```

I know it's not quite an answer to your question, "What am I doing wrong?" - I started working through the issues in your approach and I hit enough snags so that I felt it might just be easier to present a working solution and annotate it clearly.  Hopefully this will make it easier to see the various challenges involved and give you some insight into your initial attempt, also.

First, to deal with the issue of dead URLs, I'd recommend using `safely()` or `possibly()`.  They are nice `tryCatch`-style wrappers that give you options for how to surface errors, plus they have intuitive syntax.  So you can start by constructing the list of all the URLs you're interested in:

```
combos <- expand.grid(team=teamsVector, date=datesVector)
urls <- paste0(URL.base, combos$date, combos$team, URL.end)

urls
[1] "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909080chi.htm"
[2] "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909080crd.htm"
[3] "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909080car.htm"
[4] "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909050chi.htm"
[5] "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909050crd.htm"
[6] "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201909050car.htm"
```

And then feed that into a `possibly`-wrapped `read_html()`, using `map()`:

```
urls %>% 
  map(possibly(read_html, otherwise = NA_character_)) # throw NA if bad URL
```

The bad URLs will yield an `NA` value of type `character`, so we can `discard()` the return entries that are characters (everything else will be some HTML object):

```
discard(is.character) %>%
```

This leaves us with a list of valid scraped web pages, and we can use `map()` again to iterate over that list and pull out the table data.  The `pluck()` function is a nice way of subsetting into a list, to get that `[[3]]` table index you wanted:

```
map(function(html) html_nodes(html, 'table') %>% html_table) %>%
  pluck(3) %>%
```

One tricky thing about these tables is that they have multi-index columns - the top column contains categories like "Passing" or "Receiving", and the sub-column specifies a statistic ("TD", "Int", etc.).  That's not easy for R to put into a data frame, as it's expecting one set of column names, not two.  This requires a bit of hacking.  I chose to pull out the column and sub-column names and combine them with an underscore (e.g. "Passing_TD"):

```
# note: map_dfr just specifies a data frame output, joined row-wise
map_dfr(function(data) {
    col_lvl1 <- colnames(data)
    col_lvl2 <- data[1, ] %>% unname
    actual_data <- data[2:nrow(data), ] %>% unname
    col_multi_lvl <- paste(col_lvl1, col_lvl2, sep = "_")
    colnames(actual_data) <- col_multi_lvl
    return(actual_data %>% as_tibble(.name_repair = make.names))
  }) %>%
```

And finally there's the added issue of the tables repeating column names about halfway through each table.  I'm not sure how you want to handle that, as it looks like it may be very different information in each sub-table.  Since I'm just trying to demonstrate methods, I chose to leave those rows out and act as if all the rows belong in one big table.  Afterwards I reverted the numeric columns back to numeric data types (all the numeric cols were redefined as character data types because they had those rows with the column names in them, which are strings).

```
  filter(str_detect(Passing_Cmp, "Passing|Cmp", negate = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-starts_with("X_")), as.numeric)
```

Comment: wow, this is great! I appreciate it! The explanation is very helpful too, thank you. However, I have many dates and teams in 2 csv files (dates.csv and teams.csv) and when I use these I get this error: `Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x object 'Passing_Cmp' not found i Input `..1` is `str_detect(Passing_Cmp, "Passing|Cmp", negate = TRUE)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: is there also a way to include the week and season no. as I would like to run this across multiple seasons? I don't think these appear in the tables so not sure it can be done?

Comment: hi - in your post, you framed the problem as pulling directly from a URL, not from a CSV.  that's a different approach entirely.  can you confirm that this code runs without error and returns the data you're expecting from these webpages?  that's the first place to start.

Comment: as for your second question, i don't know.  the best way to tackle whatever problem you're working on is one step at a time.  it's better to open a new question that has a separate issue, than to try and add on in comments within the same question.

Comment: yes it runs without errors and return the data I'm expecting. Above I did say that I am going to have a really long vector with multiple dates and teams, I should have been clearer on this. I will consider the second question separately.

Comment: Ok - it sounded like "multiple dates and teams" mapped onto the multiple dates and teams used to construct the URLs you provided.  This method should work for any number of dates and teams, as long as it's pulling from a URL directly.  If you want to read in data from a CSV, I'm not sure how the code would have to change to fit that approach.  Would be good to have an example to work with.